# How to print the no of rows in one line with "* ~" in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

If I place my cursor in 1st row then except that row value I want all the rows to concatenate. next if I place the cursor in 2nd row then except that row I need all the rows to concatenate , this is to be done for `n` number of rows.

```
Sub concatenate()
    Dim x As String
    Dim Y As String

    For Q = 1 To 1 'This provides a column reference to concatenate - Outer For statement
        For T = 1 To 24 'This provides a rows reference to concatenate - Inner for statement

            For Each cell In Cells(T, Q) 'provides rows and column reference
                Set rng = Range("A1", "A20")
                If cell.Value = "" Then GoTo Line1  'this tells the macro to continue until a blank cell is reached
                x = x & "*" & "~" & cell.Value 'This provides the concatenated cell value and comma separator
            Next ' this loops the range
        Next T  'This is the inner loop which dynamically changes the number of rows to loop until a blank cell is reached

    Line1:
        On Error GoTo Terminate 'Terminates if there are less columns (max 10) to concatenate

        ActiveCell.Value = Mid(x, 7, Len(x) - 1) 'This basically removes the last comma from the last concatenated cell e.g. you might get for a range 2,3,4, << this formula removes the last comma to
        'give 2,3,4

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Once the concatenated result is pasted into the cell this moves down to the next cell, e.g. from F1 to F2

        x = ""  'The all important, clears x value after finishing concatenation for a range before moving on to another column and range

    Next Q 'After one range is done the second column loop kicks in to tell the macro to move to the next column and begin concatenation range again

    Terminate: 'error handler
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Edit your question and use the `{}` button provided to format your code

Comment: sir help me out in this code

Comment: What error are you getting. What answer are you expecting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I have data in A column, if place the cursor in B2 row except that row I want all the rows to concatenate  and next if I place the cursor in B3 row except that row I want the rows to cancate like this until the row is null I want this output